# Remapping Logitech G5 mouse buttons

Tags: windows-vista, logitech-mouse

I just got a Logitech G5, which is a great mouse, but one 'feature' is really annoying: the middle mouse button has 3 click points, namely scroll left, scroll right and the standard scroll wheel middle click.

Because I often accidentally click the scroll left/right button when I actually wante to use the middle mouse button (e.g., to close a tab in Firefox), I want to remap both scroll buttons to the middle mouse button action. Is there a way to do this? I've tried using Logitech's SetPoint tool, but it doesn't seem to allow remapping these keys to the generic middle mouse button action (you CAN remap it to 'middle button', but it doesn't seem to do anything).

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [UberOptions](http://uberoptions.net/), which allows easy remapping of any of the keys much better than the official setpoint configuration.

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick (I can remap it to the middle mouse button now). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap these "buttons".

According to [this topic](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic27141.html) on their forum, it is possible to map "WheelLeft" and "WheelRight" since version 1.0.48.

The script to use would look this way, for you:

```
WheelLeft::return
WheelRight::return
```

It would remap the both actions to do nothing (returns directly).

However, from what I can read on the same topic, it seems that the left and right events are not working in Windows XP.

**Edit:** I misunderstood the actual question.

To remap these left and right to the middle button, you would rather use such script:

```
WheelLeft::MButton
WheelRight::MButton
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could disable the buttons with Logitech's SetPoint, but I would rather remap the keys, as I often accidentally click them.

Answer (score 1):

#### [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)

> X-Mouse Button Control is a Windows application to remap your mouse buttons and expand the capabilities of your mouse!
>
> You are able to provide application or window specific mappings, which means an application or window can use the mouse buttons differently from another. For each profile you can optionally define up to 5 'layers' of different button configurations which you can switch between using hotkeys or mouse buttons.